# How can I run an EXE Flash App on my android device?

Tags: files

Basically I have an EXE file that executes a lot of SWF files in another folder running an interactive slideshow type thing.

Is there anyway that I can de-compile the EXE file or something in such a way that I can execute it to run the slideshow on my android device?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

That's a big "Probably not". Even if you could replace the EXE, you run into the fact that Android hasn't supported Flash officially in a few years.

If you want to just run the SWF's without the EXE, you can still [manually install Adobe Flash Player](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/installing-flash-player-android-devices.html) together with [SWF Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.issess.flashplayer&hl=en), but compatibility these days is probably hit-or-miss (mostly misses I believe). If it *does* work on your device, interactive SWF's may have problems.

But if it's worth a shot, it's worth a shot.